# Creating a bijection to verify possible int sums

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Alright, so I was asked to find the number of possible solutions to the inequality:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 11$$

So, I was told to use an auxiliary variable to instead show:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 11$$

which would have $C(14, 3)$ many solutions. Since I solved the problem this way, I have to create a bijection between these two sets.

where for all $x >= 0$ in $R+$

$$ T = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 11\}$$

and

$$ Q = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 11\}$$

so the function that I want to prove is,   $f: T \to Q$, which is

$$f:(x_1, x_2, x_3) \to (x_1, x_2, x_3, 11- (x_1 + x_2 + x_3))$$

So from this point, I will attach a link-to-photo for the proof that the function is bijective, and can someone tell me if it's right or if it can be done better.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxyiy8eWvnK4VG9kN3VNbEszaE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In your definitions of set T and set Q, perhaps you meant the c2's before the bars to really be x2's (which would make more sense).

Comment: ... and set Q should have an x4?

Comment: Sorta, x4 is predetermined by 11-(x1 + x2 + x3)

Comment: ...yeah but the elements of Q are quartupletes.  If you don't list the x4 then you are claiming the elements are triplets.

Comment: It's impossible to know whether the claim is even right as long as you're not disclosing what $x_1, x_2, x_3$ range over? The real numbers? The positive integers? The non-negative integers?

Comment: I just realized you never stated whether xi are positive or not (or whether they are integers.  is x4 is allowed to be less than 0 then this is not bijective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T = \{(x, y, z)| (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{+3}, x + y + z \le 11\}$

Let $Q = \{(a, b, c, d)| (a,b ,c ,d) \in \mathbb R^{+3}, d = 11 - (a + b+ c + d) \}$

That each term be non-negative is a requirement for bijectivity.

Injective:

Need to show that if $f(x, y, z) = (a, b, c, d)$ there is only one possible value in $T$ for $(x, y, z)$

$f(x, y, z) = (x, y, z, 11 - (x+ y + z)) = (a, b, c, d)$ so the only possible value so $(x, y, z) = (a, b, c)$ is the only possible value.  So injective.

Surjective.

For every possible $(a, b, c, d) \in  Q$ we must show there exists a value $(x, y, z) \in T$ s.t. $f(x, y, z) = (a, b, c, d)$.

If $(a, b, c, d) \in Q$, then $a + b + c +d = 11$ so $d = 11 - (a + b + c)$ and $d,a,b,c > 0$ so $a + b + c = 11 - d < 11$. So $(a, b, c) \in T$.

$f(a, b, c) = (a, b, c, 11 - (a+b+c)) = (a, b, c,d)$.  So $f$ is surjective.